Cambiar el directorio de datos de prostgesql a carpeta compartida en virtualbox
he construido una maquina virtual (virtualbox 7) con ubuntu server 24.04, he instalado los Guest Additions para linux y he compartido una carpeta entre anfitrión (Linux Mint 21.3) y la máquina virtual, hasta aquí todo funciona bien, el servidor guest tiene acceso a la carpeta compartida tanto de lectura como escritura.
Posterior a eso, sobre la máquina virtual he instalado Postgresql 16, el cual funciona correctamente, pero al intentar cambiar el directorio de datos (se han seguido varias guias encontradas en internet) a una carpeta dentro de la carpeta compartida del SO Anfitrión (La VM tiene poco disco duro asignado y el objetivo es que los datos queden a su vez en la máquina anfitrión) Postgresql no sube de forma correcta, ya que al intentar acceder indica que el puerto 5432 no esta en funcionamiento.

Después de varias pruebas al parecer la causa son los propietarios de la carpeta compartida que se monta en virtualbox (root:vboxsf) y que no se pueden cambiar por los de postgres:postgres. Solución, montar una máquina virtual con KVM/Qemu, adicionar un File System con driver virtiofs, configurar el fstab para que monte la unidad al iniciar la máquina y cambiar los propietarios del punto de montaje a postgres:postgres
